# Database Storage: Individual Player Keys vs. One Key to a Dictionary of Players

Tags: python, database, discord.py, game-development, replit

So I am currently developing a multiplayer text game within a Discord Bot. I am currently using Repl.it to host and run my bot and Repl comes with a build in database, but there is a small catch: you are only allowed a certain amount of keys, size of keys, and total size of database ([Database Restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fhwg.png)).

Keeping in mind Repl's max of 5000 keys per database, 5 MB per value, and 50 MB in total, how should I structure my database to store individual players (stats, inventory, etc.) and world data (interactive tile data of a 200x200 world, player coords, etc.)?

Should the database have a "players" key and a "tiles" key both connected to (potential) large dictionary storing all of the players and tiles respectively? Or should the database have individual keys for each player and world tile and use something like database prefixes ([Prefix search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKy5w.png)) to access the keys when needed for a specific player? Or a mixture of both to optimize both maximum use of Repl's limits and ease of use?

This question is meant to be very open ended, and criticism of my uses for a database are also welcome. Thank you so much for the help and advise in advanced :)

Comment: How many players are you expecting?

Comment: @Chuaat We have an active server of people interested, but we aren't expecting any more than 100 players.

Comment: Your best bet would be to have 10 keys which all have 5 MB of data in them, allowing for approximately 6553600 characters. When you want to have the data of a certain player, you go through each key, and check if the player is in there.

Comment: @Chuaat Do you think that 100 total players and some world data will reach the databases max storage? This sounds too complicated...

Comment: Depends on how much data you store per player. If you want to store 5000 pictures per player, that's obviously not goind to work

Comment: I'd suggest an alternative: Although this doesn't answer the question, I feel like such a program would benefit from having a larger database with less limits. Possible alternatives include a CSV file in the root folder, or more complex alternatives like a SQLite database as a file on the root folder. Specific files don't have limits, as long as the whole Repl doesn't exceed a certain size: Therefore, you aren't restricted to a certain number of users or data. I generally only use Replit's database for things like configuration settings, timestamps for actions, etc., not as a full database.